# SQL Server Mirroring Many DBs

Tags: sql-server, performance, mirroring

We have two identical servers running SQL Server 2017.

Let's call them A and B. A is hosting 12 databases and B is hosting 6 databases.

Each server is synchronously mirroring its DBs on the other one, so that A has 12 running DBs and 6 restoring DBs; B has 6 running DBs and 12 restoring DBs.

Would there be a benefit to running all the DBs on the same server and have all the restoring DBs on the other one? We have many queries that join tables from different DBs/servers.

Previously, the DBs were not mirrored and we were running two servers to spread the load. But now that we're synchronously mirroring all the DBs, each write must occur on both servers. It makes me think that the performance gain of having the DBs on two servers is nil.

We're a registered charity and we get our Windows/SQL licenses from TechSoup for dirt cheap, so licensing price is not a factor.

Comment: Cross-server queries will definitely hurt you. I assume you use linked servers for these? The difference between query between 2 tables on the same vs on a different server can be enormous. There's no difference between same same or different databases in the same instance. Apart from that, spreading the load across servers can help you since load is so much more than just applying modifications.

Comment: Depends what your overall goals here are. Spreading out the workload? Disaster recovery? Are all databases equally important? Tibor's cross-db comment is also a good one to consider. If you're a charity, consider posting on [To Catch A Fire](https://www.catchafire.org/) to try to find some free consulting on your db architecture.

Comment: IO on the log files with be HIGHER with mirroring than with Availability Groups. AGs have much improved performance over mirroring. (Also mirroring is deprecated)... Personally, I'd look at doing an Availability Group or two, and once they are up and running you can experiment with what arrangements of AGs gives you the best performance...

Comment: Thanks for your insights. The servers are located in the same rack, disaster recovery is done another way. There are some databases that are more important than others, they are not on the same machine.

Thanks for making me realize that, since most of our transactions are read only, it doesn't seem like moving everything to the same server would be of great benefit.

Thanks for the pointer to To Catch A Fire, I didn't know about them, I'll take a look. It's also one of our mid-term goals to replace Mirroring with Availability Groups.